# toggle function happening on second click

Tags: jquery

```
function toggleDiv()
    {
        $('#myDiv').toggle(function()
        {
            $('.pnlMyarea').slideDown();
            $('#separator').hide();
            $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '15px');
        },
        function()
        {
            $('.pnlMyarea').slideUp();
            $('#separator').show();
            $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '42px');
        });
    }
```

i am using this function to toggle my panel but this is happening on the second click not on the first what is the error.

Comment: When is `toggleDiv` executing?

Comment: i am using images in list items and on clicking of one image i am calling this function well i am using one of the simillar approach you answered yesterday

Answer (score 3):

Switch the two functions around

Comment: in that case it requires 3 clicks

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are some uncertainties in toggle functions. Not by design or feature, but by way we use it. I have myself faced this issue many times, as in like, if I set toggle visibility handler on ahref click, and some other action hide it/show it by some other event like ajax load, toggle will not keep track of it, it will do what it is supposed to do, i.e. *alternate action to previous*. Also, you have to maintain the sequence of both toggling functions, yourself.

So for toggling requirements like such hide/show, I drilled down a much more obvious and controlled solution. Check the code. This way I can show/hide even by some other event and it will be tracked commonly by a class `showing`. Helpful in long run and when you have alot of events handling on page. Trust me.

```
function toggleDiv(div)
    {
        if($(div).hasClass('showing'))
        {
            $('.pnlMyarea').slideUp();
            $('#separator').show();
            $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '42px');                
            $(div).removeClass('showing');
        }
        else
        {        
            $('.pnlMyarea').slideDown();
            $('#separator').hide();
            $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '15px');
            $(div).addClass('showing');
        }
    }
```

or simply

```
function toggleDiv()
    {
        if($('.pnlMyarea:visible').length > 0)
        {
            $('.pnlMyarea').slideUp();
            $('#separator').show();
            $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '42px');                
        }
        else
        {        
            $('.pnlMyarea').slideDown();
            $('#separator').hide();
            $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '15px');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myBtn').click()(function(){
    $('#myDiv').toggle(function()
    {
      $('.pnlMyarea').slideDown();
      $('#separator').hide();
      $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '15px');
    },
    function()
    {
      $('.pnlMyarea').slideUp();
      $('#separator').show();
      $('#manualInsert').css('margin-top', '42px');
    });
  });
});
```